# Why does the default create-react-app application make service workers immediate deleted/redundant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I would like to add push notifications to my react app. This requires service workers, but I am having no luck getting them to work. I have run `npx create-react-app test` and amended the App.js as such (line 5, `navigator.serviceWorker...` is the only change):

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service_worker_test.js");

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and added service_worker_test.js to the public folder with just this:

```js
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
  console.log("[Service Worker]", "activated");
});
```

when I run it using `npm start`, it loads in the browser and logs `[Service Worker] activated`. But in the chrome dev tools, it shows the service worker as `<location> - deleted` and the status is `redundant`.

Creating a non-React app with service workers and push notifications works perfectly fine for me on the same environment.

Why is it doing this? Thanks!

Comment: you need to comment out the `unregister()` line. there contains comments why and link to reasoning

Comment: Update: that worked, thank you so so much. I even read through that whole file and it just never "registered" with me (pun intended) that that was always unregistering whatever was "ready". If you post this as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default behavior](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) for CRA is to disable service workers.

As a result of this default, to use a custom SW as you are, either delete or comment out the line calling `serviceWorker.unregister()`.

Example with **custom service worker enabled, `serviceWorker.unregister()` deleted**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service_worker_test.js");
```

Comment: I don't want to use their service worker though. I am writing a push notification library that installs it's own.

Comment: Thanks, you should also update the comment above the code though as it is now using ```navigator.serviceWorker``` instead of the serviceWorker imported on line 5.

The removal/commenting out of that ```serviceWorker.unregister()``` is the integral part as per George's comment, as if you don't do that and just add ```navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service_worker_test.js");```, then the unregister call will gladly unregister the "service_worker_test" worker

Comment: thanks but it's still not *quite* correct (though a lot clearer). "delete or comment out the line calling navigator.serviceWorker.unregister()" should just be "delete or comment out the line calling serviceWorker.unregister()".

Thanks!